# Word for willingness to change your mind

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, vocabulary

Is there a word for a high willingness to change your mind/opinion/definition if proven wrong or shown a more accurate truth?

Comment: I would say "scientist" or "scientific".

Comment: @HotLicks Some scientists may take offense.

Comment: @Kris - Then they're not scientists.

Answer (score 3):

[**Open-minded**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/open-minded?q=open-minded) means

> willing to consider ideas and opinions that are new or different to
>   your own.

Answer (score 1):

"Prepared to stand corrected"

> Senator Flynn: I thought that was the case, but if I am wrong I am prepared to stand corrected. ([Canada. Parliament. Senate, 1974](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=s99JAQAAIAAJ))
>
> I am prepared to stand corrected if someone provides a concrete example of … ([Reasonable Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AReasonable_man), WP)
>
> I believe that 4H is the best bid possible, though am prepared to stand corrected. ([the-west-australian, 9 Feb 2018](https://www.pressreader.com/australia/the-west-australian/20180209/281998967913434))

Answer (score 0):

**malleable**   [dictionary.com](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/malleable)

> capable of being changed, changeable, molded, trained, etc.; adaptable

and from [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/malleable):

> A malleable [person or] personality is capable of being changed or
>   trained.

As in:

> It's easier to learn when you're young and **malleable**. Some, who fancy themselves moderates, admire the businessman’s **malleability**.   But
>   one-fifth of the public lacks a clear positive or negative feeling
>   about the law, a sign that opinions are still **malleable**.

Malleable can connote manipulation. My sense of being capable of changing one's mind in the face of new facts or information is a desirable malleability.

Comment: @Jim Agree. It can suggest such. I edited and provided my sense as to unforced changeability.